# select count case calculation

Tags: sql-server, count, calc

I have an MS query that selects the count of two different records and then performs a calculation to subtract one result from the other and display the result as `difference`.

See below:

```
Ticketnumber   |   Createdon    |    Modifiedon  |
00012121       |    16/03/2015  |    15/03/2015  |
00211335       |    10/03/2015  |    17/03/2015  |

SELECT  ( SELECT    COUNT(incidentbase.ticketnumber) AS val2
          FROM      IncidentBase
          WHERE     createdon >= GETDATE() - 7
        ) - ( SELECT    COUNT(incidentbase.ticketnumber) AS val1
              FROM      incidentbase
              WHERE     modifiedon >= GETDATE() - 7
            ) AS difference
```

What I would like is to display the result as a single value depending on whether the result is a positive number, or a negative number, something similar to:

```
WHEN difference => 0 then 1
WHEN difference =< 0 then 0
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN (SELECT COUNT (incidentbase.ticketnumber) as val2 
                FROM IncidentBase 
                WHERE createdon >= GETDATE()-7) - 
               (SELECT count (incidentbase.ticketnumber) as val1 
                FROM incidentbase 
                WHERE modifiedon >= GETDATE()-7) <= 0 THEN 1
          ELSE 0 
       END AS flag
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'case' like this:

```
declare @i1 int=5
select case when @i1 < 0 then 0 
when @i1=> 1 then 1 
end  results1
```